# Interface Object syntax in F#

Tags: c#, syntax, f#

I'm translating C# code for multipage printing into F# . Could somebody tell me how to translate:

```
((IAddChild)page1Content).AddChild(page1)
```

context:

```ml
       // printdia = printdialog
       // printdoc = printdocument

       // create a page
       let page1 = new System.Windows.Documents.FixedPage()
       page1.Width <- printdoc.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Width
       page1.Height <- printdoc.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Height
       page1.Children.Add(printcanvas) |> ignore
       // add the page to the document
       let page1Content = new System.Windows.Documents.PageContent()
 (*C#*)((IAddChild)page1Content).AddChild(page1)
       printdoc.Pages.Add(page1Content) |> ignore
       // and print
       printdia.PrintDocument(printdoc.DocumentPaginator, ordernr.Text);
```

[Original code in C#](http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/20/wpf-printing-part-2-the-fixed-document.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `page1Content.AddChild(page1)` does not work, try `(page1Content :> IAddChild).AddChild(page1)`.